# Problems attempting to run code analysing reference list for reading

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, list, text

Trying to analyse a list of references from my repository in attempting to prioritize articles to read first.

First tried to place an 'eval' before calling file from dir, i.e. ...pd.DataFrame(eval("File") because error message told I tried to do a string, then I got a syntax error, saying that I was doing the file call incorrectly. Don't you normally use "" to call a file in pandas? Help needed, thx...;o)

```
from collections import Counter
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style("white")

publication_data = pd.DataFrame("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\My_Collection_test1.txt")

publication_data.dropna(subset=['EDAT'], inplace=True)

publication_data["Year"] = (

publication_data["EDAT"].astype(str).str[0:4].astype(int)

)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=600)

# Top 10 authors

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)

authors_flat = [

author

for authors in list(publication_data["FAU"].dropna())

for author in authors

]

top10authors = pd.DataFrame.from_records(

Counter(authors_flat).most_common(10), columns=["Name", "Count"]

)

sns.barplot(x="Count", y="Name", data=top10authors, palette="RdBu_r")

plt.title("Top 10 Authors")





# Publications over Time

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)

yearly = pd.DataFrame(publication_data["Year"].value_counts().reset_index())

yearly.columns = ["Year", "Count"]

sns.lineplot(x="Year", y="Count", data=yearly)

plt.title("Publications over Time")

plt.xlim([1986, 2020])





plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)



# TOP 10 Journals

top10journals = pd.DataFrame.from_records(

Counter(publication_data["TA"]).most_common(10),

columns=["Journal", "Count"],

)



sns.barplot(x="Count", y="Journal", data=top10journals, palette="RdBu_r")

plt.title("Top 10 Journals")



# Top associated keywords

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)



flat_kw = [

_.lower()

for kws in list(publication_data["OT"].dropna())

for kw in kws

for _ in kw.split(" ")

]



top10kw = pd.DataFrame.from_records(

Counter(flat_kw).most_common(10), columns=["Keyword", "Count"]

)



sns.barplot(x="Count", y="Keyword", data=top10kw, palette="RdBu_r")

plt.title("Top 10 Associated Keywords")

plt.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, left=0, right=1, hspace=0.3, wspace=0.3)

plt.show()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/jcst/PycharmProjects/TextMining/Test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    publication_data = pd.DataFrame(eval("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\My_Collection_test1.txt"))
  File "<string>", line 1
    C:\Users\jcst\Desktop\Private\Python data\My_Collection_test1.txt
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\My_Collection_test1.txt")` this should be `pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\My_Collection_test1.txt")` , with a proper seperator eg: `\t` for tab. `pd.DataFrame()` cannot read a file directly

Comment: Thx, of course - how could I possibly miss that...shame on me…;o)….shouldn't it then be pd.read_txt?

Comment: does pandas have a `read_txt` ?

Comment: Seemed to recall that, yet you win…;o)